# Develop QR Scanner to scan "only" the QR codes i Generate?

Tags: android, c++

I need help! i am a digital marketer and obsessed with QR codes. I want to create my own " QR Scanner" that can only scan " QR codes i have Generated". I know an Israeli company did the same thing for Alibaba to fight counterfeit products..Yet i can figure out how they did it? help??? Link: https://www.wired.com/2015/05/alibaba-reveals-retro-way-fight-counterfeits-qr-codes/

Comment: How much experience do you have with computer vision and related technologies?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to encode encrypted data in a QR code. But keep in mind that a QR code can only hold a limited amount of information.

Answer (score 2):

A QR-Code and store up to 2,953 bytes. All you need to do is store your data, followed by a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Once you have that, all you have to do is have your reader include your public key and use that to verify the signature.

The only problem here is the limited amount of space: every bit the signature uses, is a bit less you can have for your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own scanner and "QR" codes then you are looking at image anayalis technologies and a lot of work. Making somthing that can not then be simply forged is even harder. e.g. normal QR codes are just black to make them easy to print and analyze. If you just change how the data is represented, it is easy for people to figure out how to clone or modify them.

If your just interested in making your application verify the payload Id just see about digitally signing (with a keypair) or otherwise validating the data referenced by the QR code in some way. e.g. if they are URL's I might say they must be URLs to https://example.com/qr-codes/foo. This would prevent other people creating their own QR codes with modified data, but it would still be fairly easy for people to copy your authentic QR codes exactly.